# Run stored procedure for multiple rows & record success/failure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have the below table which gets loaded into my DB each night (this usually contains more rows, but I have just included 2 for example).

I then have a stored procedure called `[dbo].[StitchUsernames]` which accepts the `UserID` as a parameter. This stored procedure takes the `UserID` and updates another table to say that the `UserID` has been successfully imported.

What I am trying to achieve have the stored procedure run for every row in the table & record the outcome of the stored procedure run (success/fail) in the `StitchResult` table.

What would be the best way to achieve this? So for the below example, I would want it to run for `UserID = 455` and then update `StitchResult` to success/error. Then it would move on to 22 and do the same.. until all rows have been worked through.

```
  UserID           Username         StitchResult
  ----------------------------------------------
   455              Peter.S            NULL
   22               Maureen.T          NULL
```

Appreciate any advice! I have tried looking at cursors but was reading these can cause performance issues?

Comment: If you must call a stored procedure for each row, you'll need to use a cursor. It would be better to refactor the proc as a set-based operation for multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to achieve this using the below method in azure data factory.. hopefully it is useful to someone else!

https://helicaltech.com/lookup-foreach-activity-azure-data-factory/